# Xamarin: Using native libraries in MVVMCross

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

Building a cross platform app that utilizes a native C library (using P/Invoke) to send commands to a remote server, how can it be architected to suit the MVVMCross framework?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear which framework(s) you are using.

Assuming iOS, see how to use P/Invoke at http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/native_interop

After getting the P/Invoke to work, if you need to access this in PCL code, then you'll need to use some form of dependency injection technique - one such technique is plugins - https://speakerdeck.com/cirrious/plugins-in-mvvmcross

Comment: A cross platform app (Android & iOS) that uses a native C library (two libraries compiled for iOS & Adnroid) needs System.Runtime.interopServices but, the profile 104 PCL consists the .NET subset that doesn't include this assembly. So, is it still possible to use the native C library? Do, we put the reference to the native library in the View project or inside PCL project?

Comment: PCL is for portable code. For non-portable code, you'll need to add that code to a native library or to the native UI and then use an interface or abstraction to use it from within the PCL.